# How can i write jmeter test result in csv file via cmd?

Tags: jmeter

I can get the result of jmeter in a csv file using GUI mode but to save test result in a csv file using cmd? That is, what is the command and its parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for this This is the command for csv file output via cmd  -Djmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv